# How to resolve dll binding in MSTest Visual Studio 2012

Tags: c#, unit-testing, reference, visual-studio-2012, mstest

When trying to right click on a test on Visual Studio 2012 -> Run Tests,
I am getting error messages that dlls were not found.

> "System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly
>   'Recipe.API, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' or
>   one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified."

Doing the same in Visual Studio 2010 is working and the test is passing.

The dlls are placed under bin directory, but in different directory than output directory of the proj

(I configured the testsetting file)

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure to [**Select Test Settings File**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ee256991)

[image: Select Test Settings File]

Comment: Yes it was the problem, I just found it yesterday and came to write my answer here but you already did it! thanks..

Comment: In vs2010 after creating test setting file by default you will get the testsetting to be active, but in vs2012 you need to select him..